# How to save padding around an icon and make it a part of it - Photoshop CS3

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon, marquee-tool

I have an icon with the dimensions `24px × 23px`. The canvas is `24px × 24px`: There is 1 transparent pixel at the top of the icon.

After I use the rectangular marquee tool to copy and paste the icon to another psd document I get the icon as `24px × 23px`. But i need it to be `24px × 24px`.

How do I copy the dimensions with the transparent pixel to a new document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't copy/paste transparencies. There has to be some content. I don't see why you can't just position the element where you want in the new icon, but an alternative and not too clean way to have a 24x24px pasted icon would be to add a single pixel with 1% transparency to the area that you want empty.

Comment: Thanks. The reason why i don't wanna position the element in the new icon is because i am builing image sprites and doing so is time consuming.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense!

Comment: @RayZ I don't knnow what you are doing _exactly_, but Smart object keeps transparencies. One pretty easy way to bring images into PS document as Smart objects, would be to select bunch of images in a folder and drag them into an open document in photoshop. Aside from that, you might want to consider using something like this: http://spritegen.website-performance.org/